# What is the "wide place" in Psalm 119:45?

Tags: psalms

Psalm 119:44-45:

> I will keep your law continually,
> forever and ever,
> **and I shall walk in a wide place**,
> for I have sought your precepts.

What, exactly, is the "wide place" in this context and what does it symbolize? Is it referring to a place that is safe to walk, or to a place that is easy to walk? Or something else entirely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Ps 119:45, the ESV gives this:

> and I shall walk in a wide place, for I have sought your precepts.

Other versions provide a more interpretive translation:

- NIV: I will walk about **in freedom**, for I have sought out your precepts.
- NLT: I will walk **in freedom**, for I have devoted myself to your commandments.
- BSB: And I will walk **in freedom**, for I have sought Your precepts.
- KJV: And I will walk **at liberty**: for I seek thy precepts.
- NKJV: And I will walk **at liberty**, For I seek Your precepts.
- NASB: And I will walk **at liberty**, For I seek Your precepts.
- CSB: I will walk **freely in an open place** because I study your precepts.
- HCSB: I will walk **freely in an open place** because I seek Your precepts.

Note the comments of Cambridge Bible:

> 45. And I will walk at liberty] Lit. in a broad place, for God’s commandment is “exceeding broad”; its observance is no restraint but
>     the truest freedom. Or the meaning may be, Let me walk at liberty,
>     free from the constraint of anxiety and persecution. Cp. Psalm 119:32;
>     Psalm 118:5.

The Pulpit commentary is similar

> Verse 45. - And I will walk at liberty. Rekhabah is literally "the
> open square of a city," hence "a wide, open, free space." In obeying
> God's commandments the psalmist will not feel himself under
> constraint, but a wholly free agent. For I seek thy precepts.
> Inclination, not constraint, makes him obey God's precepts - he
> "seeks" them, "loves" them (ver. 47), "delights in" them (vers. 16,
> 24, 47). Psalm 119:45